# Installing Windows Server 2012 with a 4TB Hard Drive giving me GTP Error + deceted as 2TB

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, gpt

I'm trying to install `Windows Server 2012` for a new NAS/Backup build.
The primary error is Windows only detecting 2.2TB at install out of 4TB.

I have plugged the HDD into another computer and formatted the drive as a 4TB GPT with simple partition.

I have scoured though the motherboard's BIOS settings (Gigabyte GA-H67MA-USB3-B3) and was able to find a setting to set it to "EFI mode" with SMART enables.

Now it prompts me

> "This drive has been detected as GPT, please format to MBR to install
>   windows"

or something similar to that.

Is there something I am missing to continuously get this error?

Comment: Although the phrasing is entirely different, this is basically the same as [this question.](http://superuser.com/questions/639485/install-windows-7-ultimate-x64-as-uefi-with-gpt) You need to install Windows 7 in EFI mode, not in BIOS mode. The trick is simply getting the Windows 7 disc to boot in that mode.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, I don't think that's a good idea to have such a big OS partition anyway. A much smaller SSD for the system and the big HDD for other things would be much better.

Anyway, to answer your question:

First check if your mobo supports UEFI booting. If it does, then it is possible, but not through 'simple' meanings.

You can try to burn a DVD and install from there.

If all the above fails, read [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/05798532-d8c0-4f9e-b12f-58d3a0ee4c07/installing-windows-on-a-gpt-disk?forum=w7itproinstall). If still doesn't work, also see [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/booting.html) and scroll down till you reach the 'Windows' section. It talks about boot-loaders and such.

Comment: The OS partition would be smaller, around 200GB. I'm not in a position to get an SSD, but that is what I have done inside my personal build. Even if I did install it on a smaller SSD, the issue is the inability for Windows to use the full 4TB.
The motherboard supports "EFI" but it doesn't say UEFI anywhere, which is my biggest concern. I might try a DVD right now. Thanks for the response

Comment: Windows 7 and later can use/see disks with 4TB. My box from which I'm writing now has one HDD of 3TB and another of 4TB. Do you see the disk on that mobo as 4TB? Also, most most most (...) probably that 'EFI' is instead UEFI because EFI is/was proprietary Intel interface whereas U(nified)EFI is open.

Comment: I have hooked up a CD/DVD ROM drive and threw in a Windows 7 disk I had. After following [this link](http://www.jwgoerlich.us/blogengine/post/2009/11/05/Use-Diskpart-to-Create-and-Format-Partitions.aspx) the hard drive was once again primed as a GPT disk and as a primary partition. It still gives me the error of 
**"Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style"**

Comment: Quoting relevant parts of the text contained in the links would be better for the question.